# Populate input, when value in input changes (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two inputs, one for Landlord Name, and second for Organization Name

Here is code

```
  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{l("Name")}}</label>
                    <input #nameInput class="form-control" type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="landlord.name" required maxlength="32">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>{{l("OrganizationName")}}</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="organizationName" [(ngModel)]="landlord.organizationName" required maxlength="500">
                </div>
```

I need to populate organizationName, when I enter value in Name field. How I can do this?

Comment: You can also use some npm module in order to achieve your requirement. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngModelChange` event emitter, like:

```
<input #nameInput (ngModelChange)="onNameChange($event)" class="form-control" type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="landlord.name" required maxlength="32">
```

And define onNameChange in your component:

```
public onNameChange(name: string) {
    // implement some logic for picking the organization name
    // and update the input
    this.landlord.organizationName = 'some organization name';    
}
```

Comment: yeah. this helps. Thanks so much